# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected

Tags: asp.net, xml, http-post

I'm using a php script to http post some xml files to a .net URL.

When I submit I get the response:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form
>   value was detected from the client
>   (<?xml version="...UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE
>   cXML SYSTE...").  Description: Request
>   Validation has detected a potentially
>   dangerous client input value, and
>   processing of the request has been
>   aborted. This value may indicate an
>   attempt to compromise the security of
>   your application, such as a cross-site
>   scripting attack. You can disable
>   request validation by setting
>   validateRequest=false in the Page
>   directive or in the configuration
>   section. However, it is strongly
>   recommended that your application
>   explicitly check all inputs in this
>   case.

As I'm not using .NET I can't set ValidateRequest="false" in web.config.

Do I need to sanitize my xml before submitiing? How can I do this?

Comment: In your post, you should use php tag instead of asp.net

Comment: Not really - I'm using asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intriguing that you *can* see the full error, but are not capable of accessing the ASP.NET code. Normally, one can only see the full error when in debug mode, because in production, the error-setting is (should be) `RemoteOnly` or `Off`. This seems a configuration mistake and a potential risk on the side of the ASP.NET site.

You say *"to http post some xml files"*. If you were indeed posting *files*, you wouldn't receive this response. Maybe you can contact the site's owner and ask for him to change the form to allow file-input.

You can change your input such that it doesn't look like XML anymore, but then it isn't XML anymore either. I.e., change all `<` in `&lt;` and you'll be able to get your data through, but it must be unescaped when processed.

If this site is supposed to accept XML, it must be changed to accept XML. Either it should accept files, or it should accept HTML/XML input by turning `ValidateRequest` to off. If it is not supposed to receive XML, there's little you can do. It's like filling in a bank's payment form by putting letters in the amount-field: it just won't work (unless it was designed to work that way).

Answer (score 3):

On MVC, put below on post

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult PostMethod(Model viewModel)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `ValidateRequest="false"` in the page that's receiving the XML, not in the page that's *sending* it. If you don't have any access to the page that you're passing the XML to, then you'll need to find another way to pass the data, or transform it into another format first as pretty much anything that *looks* like HTML will cause an asp.net page to trigger this warning.

Comment: Just a note: asker said: *"I can't set ValidateRequest="false" in web.config."*

Comment: @Abel, yeah, I saw that, and thus assumed that the OP may be less than familiar with asp.net as they're "using a **php** script to http post some xml files to a .net URL", and may have their wires crossed, given the "As **I'm** not using .NET I can't set..." seemed to suggest to me, at least, that the OP might think they need to set the value on the "client" side of the request, particularly as it's usually set as a per-page directive, rather than for a whole site.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm posting to an external URL - which I don't have access to.

Comment: @thegunner - have you been given any instructions as to *how* to post to it then? If it rejects XML because of request validation then either you're sending the wrong thing, or the owner of the page should change it to `ValidateRequest="false"` =)

Answer (score 1):

XML or anything that "looks like" it, is considered dangerous by default, as a reasonable way to block XSS attacks on something expecting plaintext content.

The problem is with the resource you are submitting to, not with your code, file a bug or tech-support request with them.

Comment: Hi, yeah I can receive the files to my external URL and I know other places can receive the file. I've emailed them and am waiting on response.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ASP.NET 4.0, except for setting in page

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" />
```

add in web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

This should help